# Find the connected components of $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x\neq y\}$ with the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

My work: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x< y\}$ is path-connected, and hence is connected. It's also maximal, as if we were to add a point $(x,y)$ where $x=y$, then it wouldn't belong to $X$, and if we were to add a point $(x,y)$ with $x>y$ then there wouldn't be a path connecting it to the other points in the set.

Same for $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x> y\}$.

Does anything change if we replace $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Everything changes as we move from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb C^2$, since $\{(x, y)\mid x = y\}$ goes from being a line in a plane to being a plane in $4$-dimensional space; You can make paths around that plane, so the complement of the plane is connected. Otherwise it looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could afford to be more explicit with your proof for the first part by constructing a path for every pair of points in each of your candidate connected components. A straight line will do.

In euclidean spaces open and connected implies path connected. So your argument is there fine provided that you mention the openness of your subset.

But you could make a different argument for maximality as well. Path-connected implies connected, but the converse is not true for general topological spaces. Instead take the union of X and your singleton $\{(x,y)\}$ for some $x>y$ and prove that it is not a connected set. To do this,. take the subspace topology and show that it is the union of two disjoint open sets, namely $X$ and $\{(x,y)\}$.

You could answer your question for the $\mathbb{C}^2$ substitution by thinking about path-connectedness.